# Does Spring Batch have a feature to keep track of processed rows?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I currently use Spring Batch to update my entities through an external application which writes directly in my database through an ODBC connection.

For the sake of simplicity, I will represent a simplified version of the table schema here (referred as `importshipmentdata in the Java code below):

```
id(integer)
entity1_data1(character varying)
entity1_data2(character varying)
entity2_data2(character varying)
import_date(date_created timestamp with time zone)
```

And here is my Job Configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ImportShippingConfig {

    @Inject
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Inject
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Inject
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;
        jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<ImportShippingItem> reader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<ImportShippingItem> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        BeanPropertyRowMapper<ImportShippingItem> mapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(ImportShippingItem.class);
        reader.setSql("SELECT * FROM importshipmentdata");
        reader.setRowMapper(mapper);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<ImportShippingItem, ImportShippingItem> processor() {
        return new ImportShippingItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<ImportShippingItem> writer() {
        return new ImportShippingItemWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job ShippingImporter() {
        return jobs.get("ShippingImporter").start(importShipping()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step importShipping() {
        return steps.get("importShipping")
            .<ImportShippingItem, ImportShippingItem>chunk(5)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
    }

}
```

(Do not get offended by the `SELECT *`, I am still in the POC phase :) )

I could use the `import_date` filed but then again, I am afraid it would not handle job failures very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer while redacting the question so I will post it here.

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#process-indicator)

> By default, all of the ItemReader and ItemWriter implementations store
>   their current state in the ExecutionContext before it is committed.
>   However, this may not always be the desired behavior. For example,
>   many developers choose to make their database readers 'rerunnable' by
>   using a process indicator. An extra column is added to the input data
>   to indicate whether or not it has been processed. When a particular
>   record is being read (or written out) the processed flag is flipped
>   from false to true. The SQL statement can then contain an extra
>   statement in the where clause, such as "where PROCESSED_IND = false",
>   thereby ensuring that only unprocessed records will be returned in the
>   case of a restart. In this scenario, it is preferable to not store any
>   state, such as the current row number, since it will be irrelevant
>   upon restart. For this reason, all readers and writers include the
>   'saveState' property:

So I will just add a `processed` column to my table and change my query as `SELECT entity1_data1, entity1_data2, entity2_data1 FROM table WHERE processed = false`.

Then I will my writer change the value of the column to `true` when the item is written and set it to `saveState=false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JobRepository to get status and jobId, this repo offers all data on spring batch